# What does it mean by "$\chi$ is trivial"?

Tags: group-theory, terminology, exact-sequence

The following is taken from "A Graduate course in Algebra 1" by Moskowitz and Farmakis

$\color{Green}{Background:}$

$\textbf{Proposition:}$  For an arbitrary short exact sequence of groups

$$A\xrightarrow{\phi}B\xrightarrow{\chi}C\xrightarrow{\psi}D$$

the following are equivalent:

1. $\phi$ is surjective.
2. $\chi$ is trivial.
3. $\psi$ is injective.

$\color{Red}{Questions:}$

For the proposition 2. above, what does $\chi$ is trivial mean?

The use of the term "trivial" is confusing due to that i am not sure if the authors meant that the group is a trivial group being the identity element or they meant something else.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: One of your maps looks mislabeled -- I think you mean for one of those $\psi$ to be a $\phi$.

Comment: I think the $A\to B$ should be $\phi$.  "$\chi$ is trivial" means $\chi$ maps everything to $0$.

Comment: @walkar thank you for noticing.

Comment: @user10354138 does that mean then $\chi$ is the zero map?

Comment: @Seth yes, a map being trivial means that it sends everything to the identity.

Comment: @Coharp ah kk, thank you.

Comment: You should include what $A,B,C$ are. Do we talk about groups and group homomorphisms? For sets there need not be an identity element.

Comment: N.B. a "trivial" map of sets would often refer to a constant map. In algebra it almost always refers to a zero map or a zero object of some sort

Comment: As a general tip, you could always try proving the theorem/seeing what the hypotheses imply or try to follow the given proof and see concretely what the authors actually deduce (assuming a well-written proof) and then the definition of "trivial" might become apparent.

Comment: @DietrichBurde the objects $A,B,C$ are groups. The proposition is in a section of a chapter on groups. Sorry I should have included that.

Comment: Another way of saying that $\chi$ is trivial, is to say that $\ker(\chi)=B$.

Comment: @DietrichBurde ah kk, thank you.